# How to split a number from a regex expression in c#?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a specific pattern with the following format

```
string exp = "$(2.1)+$(3.2)-tan($(23.2)) * 0.5";
```

Using this code I get the following result

```
var doubleArray = Regex
  .Split(str, @"[^0-9\.]+")
  .Where(c => c != "." && c.Trim() != "")
  .ToList();

//result
[2.1,3.2,23.2,0.5]
```

I want to split number from `$()` . i.e. *expected result* is

```
[2.1,3.2,23.2]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: if you require numbers in brackets extract that the reason you're getting 0.5 (as its a number) is because you havent been specific

Comment: The above equation is just an example. My equation contains $(x.x) format. And I want x.x only.. I am not expert in regex

Comment: What do you want to split? Just get all matches with something like `\([(\d.]+)\)` (ie. match numbers in parentheses capturing the number).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest extracting `Matches` instead of `Split`:

```
string exp = "$(2.1)+$(3.2)-tan($(23.2)) * 0.5";

var doubleArray = Regex
  .Matches(exp, @"\$\((?<item>[0-9.]+)\)")
  .OfType<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Groups["item"].Value)
  .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("; ", doubleArray));
```

Outcome:

```
2.1; 3.2; 23.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Dmitry's answer but instead of using a sub group using a zero width look behind:

```
string str = "$(2.1)+$(3.2)-tan($(23.2)) * 0.5";

var doubleArray =
    Regex
        .Matches(str, @"(?<=\$\()[0-9\.]+")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => Convert.ToDouble(m.Value))
        .ToList();

foreach (var d in doubleArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(d);
}
```